Reference request: covariant Grothendieck construction
I'm looking for a reference which proves the equivalence between opfibrations into a category $\mathcal{C}$ and pseudofunctors $F : \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Cat}$ using the covariant Grothendieck construction: that is, given a pseudofunctor $\mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Cat}$, constructing the category whose objects are pairs $(c, x)$, with $c \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \in Fc$, and maps $(f, u) : (c, x) \to (d, y)$, where $f : c \to d$ is a map in $\mathcal{C}$ and $u : (Ff)(x) \to y$ is a map in $Fd$.
I can find plenty of references which prove the contravarient version (the equivalence between fibrations into $\mathcal{C}$ and pseudofunctors $F : \mathcal{C}^\text{op} \to \textbf{Cat}$), but as I understand it, the construction you get when you dualise this is a category whose objects are pairs $(c, x)$, with $c \in \mathcal{C}$, $x \in Fc$, and maps $(f, u) : (c, x) \to (d, y)$, where $f : c \to d$ is a map in $\mathcal{C}$ and $u : y \to (Ff)(x)$ is a map in $Fd$ (i.e, one of the maps is going the wrong way).
The best I can find is this paper, which states on page 3 that it is true, but the first reference it gives seems to make no mention of opfibrations, and the second I unfortunately can't access.

I don't think you need a reference for this, as it follows from the contravariant construction if you are aware of one detail. If you already have the contravariant Grothendieck construction, you can get the covariant one as follows: we have a composite
$$
\mathrm{OpFib}(\mathcal{C})\xrightarrow{(-)^\mathrm{op}}\mathrm{Fib}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})\simeq\mathrm{Fun}((\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op},\mathbf{Cat})\simeq\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Cat})\xrightarrow{((-)^\mathrm{op})_*}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathbf{Cat})
$$
in which each arrow is an equivalence of categories, where the first arrow is the functor sending an opfibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{C}$ to the fibration $p^\mathrm{op}\colon\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$, and the last arrow is postcomposition by the self-equivalence $(-)^\mathrm{op}\colon\mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{Cat}$. This composite equivalence is the covariant Grothendieck construction. The reason you need the last arrow in the composite is as follows: you want the functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ corresponding to your Grothendieck opfibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{C}$ to satisfy $Fc\simeq p^{-1}(c)$ for all $c\in\mathcal{C}$ (the analogous statement holds for the contravariant Grothendieck construction). But the fibration $p^\mathrm{op}\colon\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ satisfies $(p^\mathrm{op})^{-1}(c)\simeq (p^{-1}(c))^\mathrm{op}$, so just naively applying the contravariant Grothendieck construction to $p^\mathrm{op}$ gives you a functor $F'\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ satisfying $F'c\simeq(p^\mathrm{op})^{-1}(c)\simeq(p^{-1}(c))^\mathrm{op}$. We need to postcompose $F'$ with the functor $(-)^\mathrm{op}\colon\mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ to end up with the correct functor $F$.
Explicitly, given a functor $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ with associated Grothendieck opfibration $p\colon\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{C}$, the above recipe implies that that $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}$ is the category of objects $(c,x)$ with $c\in\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ and $x\in (Fc)^\mathrm{op}$, and a morphism $(c,x)\to(d,y)$ is a morphism $f\colon c\to d$ in $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ and a morphism $u\colon x\to Ff(y)$ in $(Fc)^\mathrm{op}$. Hence $\mathcal{E}$ is the category of objects $(c,x)$ with $c\in\mathcal{C}$ and $x\in Fc$, and a morphism $(d,y)\to(c,x)$ is a morphism $f\colon d\to c$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a morphism $u\colon Ff(y)\to x$ in $Fc$, which is what you wanted.

Thank you! Am I then right in thinking that the inverse construction is: given an opfibration $p : X\to\mathcal{C}$, define $F : \mathcal{C}\to\textbf{Cat}$ by $c \mapsto p^{-1}{c}$, $(f : c\to d)\mapsto (f_* : p^{-1}{c}\to p^{-1}{d})$ where $f_*(x)$ is given by a the target of a cocartesian edge with source $x$ lying over $f$? And that if we didn't postcompose with the op functor, we would instead get a pseudofunctor which mapped $c\in\mathcal{C}$ to $(p^{\text{op}})^{-1}{c}$?

Yes, both are correct. I think you originally did not postcompose with the $(-)^\mathrm{op}$-functor, because this is exactly what makes the map $Ff(y)\to x$ in $Fc$ in my answer point in this direction, and not in the opposite one as in your question (the map you said was going in the wrong way).
